# Theorems proved using combinatorial nullstellensatz that have no other known proof

Tags: nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics, polynomials

Alon's (or Alon and Tarsi's?) combinatorial nullstellensatz is a powerful algebraic tool with many applications in combinatorics and number theory. See [this](http://www.tau.ac.il/~nogaa/PDFS/null2.pdf), [this](http://arxiv.org/abs/1310.6482), [this](http://arxiv.org/abs/1008.2901) and [this mathoverflow question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/43317/how-to-recognise-that-the-polynomial-method-might-work).

I am looking for good examples of results that were proved using combinatorial nullstellensatz (or its generalisation) but have no other known proof.

Comment: You can start with the 3-choosability of bipartite planar graphs. I don't know of any other proof (but maybe nobody looked for such a proof since the Alon Tarsi paper)

Comment: @Louis: Thanks. That looks like a good candidate.

Comment: @LouisEsperet if I am not mistaken, there exists a combinatorial proof using the kernel technique (for all bipartite graphs with outdegrees at most $m$ and coloring with $m+1$ colors.)

Comment: You're completely right, thank you.

Answer (score 5):

Here is an example of a nice problem for which no combinatorial proof seems to be known. It is related to a problem studied in this paper https://arxiv.org/abs/1612.08698

Let $G$ be a $d$-degenerate graph (i.e. each subgraph contains a vertex of degree at most $d$). A classical result in graph theory is that if each vertex is given a list of $d+1$ colors, then every vertex can choose a color from its list such that the resulting coloring is proper.

Now, assume instead that each vertex of $G$ is given a list of size $d+1$ colors, except one vertex which has a list of size $d$. It can be proved with the combinatorial nullstellensatz that in this case again, each vertex can be colored with a color from its list, such that the resulting coloring of $G$ is proper (see the paper above, where a stronger result is proved when $d+1$ is prime, but the proof actually works in the weaker setting for general $d$).

I have worked on finding a combinatorial proof of this result, and I know several other researchers in the area who have studied this problem, without success.